# ViewController Type does not have member named

Tags: ios, swift

I searched similar questions but none seemed to answer my issue.  I am making a single view app.  in the class ViewController: UIViewController section I have the following code:

```
var lastToAct = 0

var gameStarted = false

var tempPlayer = BasePlayer()

var positionNumber : Int = 0

var stringPosNum : String = String(positionNumber)

var stringFromInteger : String = "\(String(positionNumber))"
```

The first five variables I get no error but the 6th and 7th ones I get ViewController Type' does not have a member named' positionNumber for the last 2 variables.  I don't know why this is.

Comment: Hmm, this seems right, can you post a screen shot of the error or the rest of the class?

Answer (score 0):

```
var stringPosNum : String = String(positionNumber)
```

The problem is that this is a stored instance variable whose default value depends on the value of *another* instance variable. You can't do that, because at instantiation time, when the default value is applied, there are *no* other instance variables, because there is no instance yet — the instance is exactly what we are in the middle of creating.

One solution: put `lazy` in front of the declaration. Another solution: if this variable is always to have this relation to the other instance variable, make it a computed variable instead of a stored variable.

Comment: And for more info, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_properties

Comment: Thanks.  I am trying to learn as much as I can but still can't get a handle on some of this stuff.  Your explanation was helpful and I will explore this more.